# Converting a query into SQL that is taking 10 seconds to show results

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have this ColdFusion code

```
<cfquery name="myqry">
select max(id) as id, count(errorid) as ecount, max(errorid) as errorid, template,line,error_message, error_type 
from mytable 
where 1=1 
group by errorid, template,line,error_message, error_type 
order by max(datein) desc
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="myrqy">
    <cfquery name="thisQ" datasource="anc">
select viewed,status,errorid,datein,error_message,error_type,
    template,id from mytable where id = #myqry.id#
</cfquery>
#get.ecount# - thisQ.errorid# - #thisQ.Error_Message - #thisQ.template#
</cfoutput>
```

I tried with this code, but it does not produce results and is throwing tons of errors; I want to bring everything under one second.

```
WITH max_id AS 
(
    SELECT
        MAX(id) AS id, 
        COUNT(errorid) AS ecount, 
        MAX(errorid) AS errorid, 
        template, line, 
        error_message,  error_type 
    FROM
        mytable 
    WHERE 
        1=1 
    GROUP BY 
        errorid, template, line, error_message, error_type 
    ORDER BY
        MAX(datein) DESC
)
SELECT
    viewed, status, errorid, datein, 
    error_message, error_type,
    template, id
FROM
    mytable mt
INNER JOIN
    max_id mi ON mt.id = mi.id
```

Comment: I don't think you need errorid in the group by.

Comment: even removing that i still get results in 10 seconds plus

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion  ..looking to your original query  you should not group by for a column that you have in an aggregation function  the aggregation function retrun just the each value of the columns in group by

so if you need  max(errorid) and count(errorid) you should avoid the group by errorid

```
    select max(id) as id
            , count(errorid) as ecount
            , max(errorid) as errorid
            , template
            , line
            , error_message
            , error_type 
    from mytable 
    group by template,line,error_message, error_type 
    order by max(datein) desc
```

You could avoid also the order by in the inner query eventually apply the order by to the outer

```
    WITH max_id AS (
      select max(id) as id, count(errorid) as ecount
           , max(errorid) as errorid, max(datein) as max_datein
           , template,line,error_message, error_type 
      from mytable 
      where 1=1 
      group by errorid, template,line,error_message, error_type 
    )

    select viewed,status,mi.errorid,datein,mi.error_message,mi.error_type,
        mi.template,mi.id
    from mytable mt
    inner join max_id mi ON mt.id = mi.id
    order by mi.max_datein
```

and  be suere you have valid index  for mytable.id

Comment: that i removed, but i get results in 10 seconds to populate the data, maybe because of an inline query, how do i fix it

Comment: you could also remove the where 1=1  is always  true so is unuseful  ..   .. and i'm  now evaluating the secodn query  ..

Comment: it gives me this error: ```Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 143
Ambiguous column name 'errorid'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 143
Ambiguous column name 'error_message'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 143
Ambiguous column name 'error_type'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 144
Ambiguous column name 'template'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 144
Ambiguous column name 'id'.```

Comment: what if i havethis condition without the max and counts: ```<cfquery name="groupedget">select id as id, errorid, template,line,error_message, error_type
 from mytable
 where errorid = #errorid#
 order by datein desc 
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="groupedget">
select * from mytable where id = #groupedget.id#
</cfoutput>```

Comment: First  ..  my query work?  second  is  faster or not ..?  ..3th you mean  without all the aggregation function?

Comment: yes to all your questions asked, in 3rd, i removed aggrgation and added a where clause for errorid and id only

Comment: @JDOB   ..but removing the aggreagtion function  you obtain a different result  .. eg: if you have not the max(id)  hen you obtain all the rows  all the rows  join with all the rows have not sense .. if you don't need the aggegation function  in you case you can execute a siimple query ... 
it would be betterif you update your question adding a proper data sample  .. the and the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out what you want to accomplish. At a glance, it seems like you want to return the most recent error, with perhaps some historical context such as how many times it has previously occurred. If I'm close, I'm not seeing a need for the CTE.